# AFNetworking PUT construct body for multi/form-data, How to log the body content/parameters sent to the API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm working on an app that has an update `API` as `PUT` method that takes an array of multiple objects as params for a batch update.

Here is the params format:

```
{
    1 =     {
        "badge_number" = 20;
        email = "test@gmail.com";
        "event_id" = 120;
        "participant_id" = 129333;
        "image" = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001...>;
        "name" = "Badge for Event 120";
        "version" = 167;
    },
    2 =     {
        "badge_number" = 20;
        email = "test@gmail.com";
        "event_id" = 120;
        "participant_id" = 129333;
        "image" = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001...>;
        "name" = "Badge for Event 120";
        "version" = 167;
    }...;
}
```

Here is how I construct the request body to include images for each object in the array param to be sent using `multipart/form-data` for the images. I was using `x-www-form-urlencoded` before but looks like the api doesn't take 64 base encoded string from `NSData` of the image.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpRequestManager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"PUT" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,@"update"] parameters:batch constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            for (NSString *order in [batch allKeys]) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:participantBatch[order][@"image"] name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%@]",order,@"update_image"] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%@].jpg",order,@"update_image"] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            }
        } error:nil];

        NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        [[manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            [subject sendNext:responseObject];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            [subject sendError:error];
        }] start];
```

For some reason the request `HTTPBody` always returns `nil`. I have `AFNetworkActivityLogger` on at `debug level` but it only shows the the header fields of the request and the response. Any idea?